# Como que eu resolvo esse erro ao tentar excluir um nó especifico de uma lista dupla encadeada?

Tags: c, banco-de-dados, lista, lista-encadeada, codeblocks

No meu projeto, estou fazendo uma lista  dupla cadeada em C, onde tem os objetivos simples, como adicionar no inicio ou fim, remover um especifico ou zerar.

Eu peguei um código raso e fui adicionando os módulos que eu precisava, usando o code blocks.

Dai na parte de adicionar a opção excluir o elemento especifico, começou a aparece  os erros que já não conseguia mais resolver.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Banco{
    int numero_conta;
    char nome_cliente[30];
    float saldo;
    struct Banco *atras;
    struct Banco *agora;
    struct Banco *prox;
    struct Banco *ant;
};
typedef struct Banco node;

void inicia(node *LISTA);
int menu(void);
void opcao(node *LISTA, int op);
node *criaNo();
void insereFim(node *LISTA);
void insereInicio(node *LISTA);
void exibe(node *LISTA);
void libera(node *LISTA);
void excluir (node *LISTA);


int main(void)
{
 node *LISTA = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
 if(!LISTA){
  printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 inicia(LISTA);
 int opt;

 do{
  opt=menu();
  opcao(LISTA,opt);
 }while(opt);

 free(LISTA);
 return 0;
}

void inicia(node *LISTA)
{
 LISTA->prox = NULL;
}

int menu(void)
{
 int opt;

 printf("Escolha a opcao\n");
 printf("0. Sair\n");
 printf("1. Exibir lista\n");
 printf("2. Adicionar cliente no inicio\n");
 printf("3. Adicionar cliente no final\n");
 printf("4. Zerar lista\n");
 printf("5. Excluir cliente especifico\n");
 printf("Opcao: "); scanf("%d", &opt);

 return opt;
}

void opcao(node *LISTA, int op)
{
 switch(op){
  case 0:
   libera(LISTA);
   break;

  case 1:
   exibe(LISTA);
   break;

  case 2:
   insereInicio(LISTA);
   break;

  case 3:
   insereFim(LISTA);
   break;

  case 4:
   inicia(LISTA);
   break;


  default:
   printf("Comando invalido\n\n");
 }
}

int vazia(node *LISTA)
{
 if(LISTA->prox == NULL)
  return 1;
 else
  return 0;
}


void insereFim(node *LISTA)
{
 node *novo=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
 if(!novo){
  printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 //Comeco ediчуo do professor
 printf("Numero conta: "); scanf("%d", &novo->numero_conta);
 printf("Nome: "); scanf("%s", novo->nome_cliente);
 printf("Saldo: "); scanf("%f", &novo->saldo);
 novo->prox = NULL;
 //Fim da ediчуo do professor

 if(vazia(LISTA))
  LISTA->prox=novo;
 else{
  node *tmp = LISTA->prox;

  while(tmp->prox != NULL)
   tmp = tmp->prox;

  tmp->prox = novo;
 }
}

void insereInicio(node *LISTA)
{
 node *novo=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
 if(!novo){
  printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 printf("Numero conta: "); scanf("%d", &novo->numero_conta);
 printf("Nome: "); scanf("%s", novo->nome_cliente);
 printf("Saldo: "); scanf("%f", &novo->saldo);

 node *oldHead = LISTA->prox;

 LISTA->prox = novo;
 novo->prox = oldHead;
}

void exibe(node *LISTA)
{
 if(vazia(LISTA)){
  printf("Lista vazia!\n\n");
  return ;
 }

 node *tmp;
 tmp = LISTA->prox;
//Edicao do professor ("%d %s %f\n", tmp->numero_conta, tmp->nome_cliente, tmp->saldo)
 while( tmp != NULL){
  printf("\n");
  printf("Numero conta: %d\n", tmp->numero_conta);
  printf("Nome: %s\n", tmp->nome_cliente);
  printf("Saldo: %f\n", tmp->saldo);
  printf("\n");
  tmp = tmp->prox;
 }
 printf("\n\n");
}

void libera(node *LISTA)
{
 if(!vazia(LISTA)){
  node *proxNode,
     *atual;

  atual = LISTA->prox;
  while(atual != NULL){
   proxNode = atual->prox;
   free(atual);
   atual = proxNode;
  }
 }
}
```

Os primeiro erro é quando adiciono o:

```
case 5:
excluir(LISTA);
   break;

undefined reference to `excluir'
```

Eu ja vi muitos tutoriais, mas nenhum deles me fez útil infelizmente.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?
Como seria para adicionar um sistema de  Excluir cliente especifico nesse meu código ?

edit:
Eu adicionei essa funçao

```
void excluir(LISTA* LISTA, int numero_conta) {
if (LISTA == 0)
    pop(list);
    else{
        node* atual = atPos (list, LISTA);

        if(atual !=null){
            node* atras = atual = atpost(list, LISTA - 1);
            atras->prox = atual->prox;

            free(atual)
                list-> menu --;
        }
    }
}
```

mas aparece o a messagem
error: unknown type name 'LISTA'|

Comment: onde é que está a função "excluir" ?

Comment: Você definiu: void excluir (node *LISTA); mas implementou: void excluir(LISTA* LISTA, int numero_conta) {. LISTA não é um tipo, o tipo é node e se são dois parâmetros você precisa especificar isso no protótipo da função.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esteja faltando a implementação da função excluir. Esse erro ocorre quando você tem a chamada do método, mas não tem a implementação. Ele está implementado?

Comment: na verdade eu ja testei vários, mas nenhum deu sucesso.]

Comment: E dai deixei sem para que alguem pudesse me dar uma base

Comment: Então, quando implementei a função excluir aqui foi tudo certo. Você editou o post e incluido a definição do método. Mas está errado pois LISTA não é tipo nenhum. Acredito que você queria colocar node. `void excluir(node *LISTA)`

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, aparentemente a sua função excluir ainda não foi implementada.
Se ela já foi implementada e está em outra parte do arquivo, posta aqui por favor.

**Mas segue um exemplo que fiz em Java:**

**(Eu sei que a pergunta é para C, mas como esse código já estava pronto coloquei somente para você entender a lógica que é a mesma caso tenha dificuldade.)**

```
public boolean ExcluirCandidato(int _p) 
{
    // Verifica se a posição informada para adicionar o novo nó é válida.
    if (_p < 0 && _p > this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        // Caso a quantidade de candidatos = 1, basta reinicializar.
        if (this.getQuantidadeCandidatos() == 1) {
            this.InicializarLista();
        }
        else
        {
            // Caso a posição seja igual a zero, iremos excluir o primeiro nó.

            No UA; // Usuário Atual

            if (_p == 0) {

               // Usuário atual = o próximo nó após o primeiro.
               UA = this.getInicioDaLista().getProximo();

               // Faz com que o ponteiro anterior receba null.
               UA.setAnterior(null);

               // Acessamos o primeiro nó e setamos o ponteiro próximo como null.
               this.getInicioDaLista().setProximo(null);

               // Mudamos o inicio da lista/
               this.setInicioDaLista(UA); 
            }
            else
            {
                // Caso seja a última posição, é o mesmo procedimento de forma inversa.

                if (_p == this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()-1) {

                    UA = this.getFinalDaLista().getAnterior();
                    UA.setProximo(null);

                    this.getFinalDaLista().setAnterior(null);
                    this.setFinalDaLista(UA);
                }
                else
                {
                    int C; // Contador
                    No PU;

                    // Remoção no meio da lista.

                    // Verificação de qual é o melhor lado para começar a percorrer a lista, inicio ou final.
                    if (_p <= (this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()/2)) {

                        C = 0;
                        UA = this.getInicioDaLista();

                        while(C < _p-1)
                        {
                            UA = UA.getProximo();
                            C++;
                        }

                        PU = UA.getProximo().getProximo();

                        UA.getProximo().setAnterior(null);
                        UA.getProximo().setProximo(null);

                        UA.setProximo(PU);
                        PU.setAnterior(UA);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        C = this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()-1;
                        UA = this.getFinalDaLista();

                        while (C > _p) {                                
                            UA = UA.getAnterior();
                            C--;
                        }
                        PU = UA.getAnterior().getAnterior();

                        UA.getAnterior().setAnterior(null);
                        UA.getAnterior().setProximo(null);

                        UA.setAnterior(PU);
                        PU.setProximo(UA);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Diminuimos uma unidade de quantidade de candidatos;
    this.setQuantidadeCandidatos(this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()-1);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: eitcha, a tag da pergunta é C, não Java!

Comment: Sim amigo, eu sei.
Como eu já tinha esse código pronto postei para ajudá-lo a entender a lógica de exclusão, que em suma é a mesma, o que muda é a implementação, mas aí é com ele né.. Acho que ninguém vai dar o código pronto, nem C.

Answer (score 0):

O código que você apresentou não é de uma lista encadeada dupla, na realidade, o programa contém uma lista encadeada simples com cabeça, pois apesar de você ter declarado 4 ponteiros em `struct Banco`, dois a mais do que o necessário, nas funções de inserção você somente utiliza o ponteiro `struct Banco *prox;` e, desse modo, cada um dos elementos da lista está ligado somente ao próximo elemento e não ao elemento anterior.

E como a lista tem cabeça, (sempre achei cabeça em lista um desperdício de memória, mas concordo que é bem mais fácil de construir e gerenciar), o algoritmo para a exclusão de um elemento é relativamente mais simples. O código abaixo provavelmente resolve o seu problema:

```
void excluir (node *LISTA, int n_conta){

   //verifica se a lista é vazia
   if (LISTA->prox == NULL){
      puts("Lista vazia!\n");
      return;
   }
   //procura o numero de conta na lista
   while(LISTA->prox){
      if(LISTA->prox->numero_conta == n_conta){
         break;
      }
      else LISTA = LISTA->prox;
   }

   //se o n. de conta não foi encontrado, informa o usuário
   if(LISTA->prox == NULL){
      puts("Numero de conta nao encontrado.");
   }
   //do contrário, exclui a conta da lista
   else{
      node* bufPtr = LISTA->prox;
      if(LISTA->prox->prox != NULL){
         LISTA->prox = LISTA->prox->prox;
      } else{
      LISTA->prox = NULL;
      }
      free(bufPtr);
      puts("Cliente excluido com sucesso!\n");
   }
   return;
}
```